# Reading a file that is inside of a folder in python

Tags: python, filepath

Good morning

What i would like to do is reading a file called "email.txt" that is inside of a folder call "templates" and "templates" is inside of a folder called "Day_10" ,so my enviroment looks something like this:

PROYECTOS
--Day_10
------templates
----------email.txt
------file_manager.py

Note: file_manager.py in inside of Day_10 and not inside of templates, file_manager.py is where i writing my code

So, email.txt has the following message: " Hello {name}"

And i write the following code in order to read the file:

```
email_txt=r"templates\email.txt"
content=""

with open(email_txt, 'r') as f:
 content = f.read()

print(content.format(name="Brayan"))
```

But when i run the code i get the following error:

```
 & D:/python.exe d:/PROYECTOS/Day_10_files/file_manager.py
 File "<stdin>", line 1
 & D:/python.exe d:/PROYECTOS/Day_10_files/file_manager.py
 ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And i don't know what to do, i've been here for hours trying to get it right. i'm on windows

Hope someone can helps me.

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the script? Please post the *full* traceback, into the question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `email_txt` is equal to `"templates\email.txt"`.

You have a back slash.

Try with forward slash:

```py
email_txt="templates/email.txt"
```

Full Code:

```py
email_txt="templates/email.txt"
content=""

with open(email_txt, 'r') as f:
 content = f.read()

print(content.format(name="Brayan"))
```

Comment: That’s likely not the issue as the file path is prefixed with `r'…'` meaning interpret as a raw string.

Comment: @S3DEV Actually it works on my local.

Comment: The issue is likely with the way the script is being *called*. Although forward slash is preferable, the string prefix assures that’s not the issue.  Nor does the traceback suggest that.

Comment: If you’d like, you can test this with: `print(r'text\umail')`, with and without the `r` prefix.  (And umail is *not* a typo)